# response.end and nested callback

Tags: node.js

**In this code I am creating a server in nodejs
In this code I think that it should first redirect the page then it should write to the file as writeFile doesn't hold the server**

```
const server = http.createServer((req, res)=>{
  const url = req.url;
  const method = req.method;
  if(url === '/')
  {
    res.write('<html>');
    res.write('<head><title>Enter Message</title><head>');
    res.write('<body><form action="/message" method="POST"><input type="text" name="message"><button type="submit">Send</button></form></body>');
    res.write('</html>');
    ***console.log("in if")***
    return res.end();
  }
  if(url === "/message" && method === "POST")
  {
    ***console.log("in if 2")***
    const body = [];
    req.on('data',(chunk)=>{ready to be read
      console.log(chunk);
      body.push(chunk);
    });
    return req.on('end',()=>{
      ***console.log("in end")***
      const parsebody = Buffer.concat(body).toString();
      const message = parsebody.split('=')[1];
      fs.writeFile("message.txt",message,(err)=>{
        ***console.log("writing to file")***
        ***`console.log(parsebody)`***
      });
      res.statusCode = 302;
      res.setHeader('Location','/');
      res.end();
    });
  }
```

so output that i Think should be

```
in if
in if 2
<Buffer 6d 65 73 73 61 67 65 3d 6a 64 73 6e 6a 65 73 6e 65 6a 73>
in end
in if
writing to file
message=jdsnjesnejs
```

but the output is coming to be

```
in if
in if 2
<Buffer 6d 65 73 73 61 67 65 3d 6a 64 73 6e 6a 65 73 6e 65 6a 73>
in end
writing to file
message=jdsnjesnejs
in if
```

I think it should first redirect then write
and 
**also I want to know which of the above lines of code triggers the redirection**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This code that is triggering the redirect should be:

```
  res.statusCode = 302;
  res.setHeader('Location','/');
  res.end();
```

From the looks, it's already correct. Are you sure this is not just a race and the writing of the file is just very quickly done, before the browser had time to do a second request?

You could put a `setTimeout(() => fs.writeFile(...), 2000)` around your `fs.writeFile` and see if it then comes in the order you expect.

Since the buffer of your console.log looks quite small, I'd suspect it's just a race: `fs.writeFile` "just" needs to write a file, whereas the redirection is a "respond to browser/socket" -> "browser interpreting response" -> "browser create new request for '/'" -> "server process new request"

Comment: Thank you really it was the race